# How do you cleanly remove Python when it was installed with 'make altinstall'?

Tags: python, linux, installation

How do you *cleanly* remove Python when it was installed with make `altinstall`? I'm not finding an `altuninstall` or such in the makefile, nor does this seem to be a common question.

In this case I'm working with Python 2.7.x in Ubuntu, but I expect the answer would apply to earlier and later versions/sub-versions.

Why? I'm doing build tests of various Python sub-versions and would like to do those tests cleanly, so that there are no "leftovers" from other versions. I could wipe out everything in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/bin` but there may be other things there I'd like *not* to remove, so having a straightforward way to isolate the Python components for removal would be ideal.

Comment: Depending on the effort you're looking at putting into this... why don't you use Vagrant and a VM per Python version?

Comment: Given that altinstall does not put anything outside of the specified folder (because usually you don’t have the rights for it), simply deleting the folder should be fine.

Comment: I'm just curious if there is a typical way to remove such an install or not. Since this installs binaries, etc in /usr/local just removing those folders may remove other things. If the answer is "there's no straightforward uninstall for altinstall" then so be it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, there’s no automatic way to do this. But you can go into `/usr/local` and delete `bin/pythonX` and `lib/pythonX` (and maybe `lib64/pythonX`).

But more generally, why bother? The whole point of `altinstall` is that many versions can live together.  So you don't need to delete them.

For your tests, what you should do is use `virtualenv` to create a new, clean environment, with whichever python version you want to use. That lets you keep all your `altinstall`ed Python versions and still have a clean environment for tests.

Also, do the same (use `virtualenv`) for development. Then your `altinstall`’ed Pytons don't have site packages. They just stay as clean, pristine references.

Comment: Virtualenv is how I'm going about this to avoid the problem, but I wondered if there is a consistent uninstall method for this. Evidently the answer is "no, not if you build it yourself" (there certainly is a way to uninstall things if you build and install Debian packages, but that's another layer). What I'm reminded of is that installing Linux packages such as Python from source is generally consistent, while uninstalling them is often arcane and unsupported.

Comment: Personally I needed to install (&remove) an older version of Python than the repositories offered. After installation, I realized that I did not have installed all optional build dependencies.

Comment: There may also be files in the `/usr/bin/include` and `/usr/bin/share/man` directories.

Comment: @thorink it's `/usr/local` not `/usr/bin`