# I can't get python to recognize OpenSSL and pip itself keeps saying that it requires SSL. What can I do?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, openssl

I was trying to update python from 3.5 to 3.11 on a server running ubuntu 16. I really messed up.

The python3.11 instance was giving me:

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

So I removed OpenSSL and tried to reinstall it (yeah, stupid, I know). This has now caused the server to stop working since nginx is now giving me the issue:

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/si...

Which is obviously because openssl wasn't reinstalled properly. When I try to make the python installation, it tells me a need openssl 1.11.1. I've tried apt-get but that's only 1.0.2g.

I tried to install 3.0.12 from the [source](https://www.openssl.org/source/) which might have been dumb but idk. It worked but the python installation wasn't recognizing it. I tried a bunch of stuff but am so exhausted that I just want the old version to work so I can stop worrying about it and try again later. The issue is that now nginx is giving me the issue I mentioned earlier and the openssl from apt-get doesn't work for the old python3.5 anymore. I can't use python3 -m pip because pip doesn't work because of the error I mentioned earlier!

I think this whole this comes from me being really stupid and deleting python and/or openssl folders that I really shouldn't have.

I've installed 2 different OpenSSL version and have tried going into the config files for both nginx and python to try and change where they look for it.

I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407527/installing-ssl-package-with-pip-requires-ssl-package-to-be-already-installed) to try and deal with the ssl pip issue, but that didn't work and even if it did probably wouldn't solve the issue of 3.5 not finding it either.

Any help that anyone can give would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why not reinstall python3.5 and use a virtual/conda env for the newer python? That way you don't need to mess up with the system.

Comment: @MEE Yeah, that's what I should have done, but the issue now is that the python 3.5 installation doesn't have SSL and so I can't use pip to install venv. When I try to use apt to install python3-venv, I get an error that "the virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available." My understanding is that I can't remove python3.5 without risking breaking the system? Is that true?

Comment: yes, `apt-get` on Ubuntu 16 needs python3.5. What happens when you do `sudo apt update --fix-missing`?

Comment: Ubuntu _16?!_ Upgrade your server, already. The low-level OS libraries are unlikely to support modern Python.