# Error when installing Python 3.12.2 with SSL module in CentOS 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos7

I've been trying to install Python 3.12.2 with the SSL module in CentOS v7.9.2009 but I'm getting an error at the end.
I have followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73415654/23392272) but I always get the same error at the end:

```
[root@server Python-3.12.2]# make altinstall
./_bootstrap_python ./Programs/_freeze_module.py abc ./Lib/abc.py Python/frozen_modules/abc.h
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/Python-3.12.2/Lib/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/src/Python-3.12.2/Lib/os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
SystemError: <built-in function compile> returned NULL without setting an exception
make: *** [Python/frozen_modules/abc.h] Error 1
```

I also get a failure in "test_embed" before that:

```
0:00:22 load avg: 0.95 [16/44] test_embed
test test_embed failed
0:00:30 load avg: 0.95 [17/44] test_float -- test_embed failed (2 errors)
```

Then, when I run Python I get the following output:

```
[root@server Python-3.12.2]# python3.12
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3.12'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/usr/local/lib/python3.12'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.12'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.12'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python312.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fb3369f7740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

When I don't use SSL Python is installed without any problem.

Following [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114549/23392272) it installs just fine but I'd like to have the latest version as my project was made in the 3.12.2 version.

What should I do to fix this?